# Android Layer-list arrangment

Tags: android, layer

i am using the following layer-list file to make a background image.

**Layer-list:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/bgpattern"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
         /> -->
         <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

             >
           <item >      
              <bitmap 
                   android:src="@drawable/bgpattern"
                   android:tileMode="repeat"

         />   
               </item>    

               <item android:drawable="@drawable/trans"

                   >      
              </item> 
              <item  android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" >      
                   <bitmap 
                   **android:src="@drawable/colordots"**
                   android:gravity="bottom"

         />   
              </item> 

      </layer-list>
```

but the **android:src="@drawable/colordots** image is appearing at center bottom of the screen i need it to be appear at the left-bottom of the screen. how can i do that can any one help me in doing this. the android:left="2dp" is not taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<bitmap android:gravity="left|bottom"/>`